# Lack of sex drive

Tags: sex

I m married for almost 6months. My husband doesn't have any sex drive. He touched me only once or twice till date. He doesn't want to go to any doctor. Please suggest me medicines to increase his drive (Note: He is not impotent).

Comment: Did he have a sex drive previously and has lost it? Also, does he want to have a sex drive?

Comment: Go to a doctor.  There are many possible causes for a lack of sex drive, some of which can be treated by medicines and some of which can't, and sometimes a medicine that can cure one cause will make a different cause worse.

Comment: If he refuses to see a doctor, as DoctorWhom rightly recommends in his/her answer, then that (his refusal) is an even bigger problem.

Answer (score 5):

See a doctor. [Low libido](http://www.webmd.com/men/features/revving-up-low-libido) (the medical term for sex drive) can have medical causes. Two examples among many potential causes are low testosterone or depression.

Also [Sex therapy](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/mindful-sex/200809/seeking-sex-therapy-primer) (a type of couples psychotherapy) is a type of counseling that is highly recommended in the medical/behavioral health field for couples with differences in sexuality that causes stress for one/other partner or both.  (This is in addition to - not a replacement for - seeking medical evaluation.)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. But he refuses to go to doctor. N he doesn't have any depression. Previously also he had d same problem, low libido.. really don't know wat to do with him.